# Accessing customer contact details with QBSDK

Tags: qbxml

According to the QBSDK v12 and v13 OSR documentation, the SDK returns contact details (phone, email, etc.) for each of the contacts associated with a customer. In other words,  tags within the contact. But when I query a customer that has multiple  contacts associated with it, all I get is:

```
<Contact>Thing One</Contact>  (for the contact flagged as primary)
<AltContact>Thing Two</AltContact>   (for the contact flagged as secondary)
<AdditionalContactRef>
  <ContactName>Main Phone</ContactName>   (the main phone # for CUSTOMER, not contact)
  <ContactValue>425-555-1212</ContactValue>
</AdditionalContactRef>
etc...
```

The phone # and email set up for each contact is not included in the response XML. This is with QB Premier 2014 and QBSDK v13. Am I missing something, or does QB not yet return the contact details, which are supposedly supported by the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for the `ContactsRet` element.

You should be able to request `ContactsRet` element using the `IncludeRetElement` element.

From the OSR:

```
<CustomerRet>
  <ContactsRet>                                 <!-- optional, may repeat -->
    <ListID>       IDTYPE       </ListID>       <!-- required -->
    <TimeCreated>  DATETIMETYPE </TimeCreated>  <!-- required -->
    <TimeModified> DATETIMETYPE </TimeModified> <!-- required -->
    <EditSequence> STRTYPE      </EditSequence> <!-- required -->
    <Contact>      STRTYPE      </Contact>      <!-- optional -->
    <Salutation>   STRTYPE      </Salutation>   <!-- optional -->
    <FirstName>    STRTYPE      </FirstName>    <!-- required -->
    <MiddleName>   STRTYPE      </MiddleName>   <!-- optional -->
    <LastName>     STRTYPE      </LastName>     <!-- optional -->
    <JobTitle>     STRTYPE      </JobTitle>     <!-- optional -->
    <AdditionalContactRef>                      <!-- must occur 0 - 5 times -->
      <ContactName>STRTYPE</ContactName>        <!-- required -->
      <ContactValue>STRTYPE</ContactValue>      <!-- required -->
    </AdditionalContactRef>
  </ContactsRet>
</CustomerRet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but unfortunately it doesn't work. Anyway, the SDK returns ALL elements if you don't specify IncludeRetElementList, so that wouldn't make a difference. I learned long ago, the hard way, not to make promises to clients based on what the OSR says I "should" be able to do. It seems like that element just isn't functional in the current versions of the SDK and QB.

Comment: From what I remember before Intuit got rid of their old forums, there were some features of the newest SDK that while they were available they did not get populated with any data. I think Additional contacts were one and something to do with Advanced Inventory as well.